# How to use Raycast Commands to cast a ray inside a Unity Job? C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this simplified version of my code that I'm working on. Briefly, I create a list of **5000 Agents** and I want each of them to perform a simple **raycast and print** if the ray hits something.

I want the tasks to be multi-threaded so I'm using for this example the `IJob` interface. The Job part of the code works OK for any other operation, but I can't make it work for simple raycasting. So here's the code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Unity.Burst;
using Unity.Collections;
using Unity.Jobs;
using UnityEngine;

public class simpleRaycast : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private List<Agent> agentList;
    public class Agent
    { }

    void Start()
    {
        agentList = new List<Agent>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
        {
            agentList.Add(new Agent());
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        NativeList<JobHandle> jobHandles = new NativeList<JobHandle>(Allocator.TempJob);

        NativeArray<RaycastCommand> raycastCommands = new NativeArray<RaycastCommand>(1, Allocator.TempJob);
        NativeArray<RaycastHit> raycasthits = new NativeArray<RaycastHit>(1, Allocator.TempJob);

        raycastCommands[0] = new RaycastCommand(Vector3.zero, Vector3.down);

        for (int i = 0; i < agentList.Count; i++)
        {
            RaycastTest job = new RaycastTest { raycastHit = raycasthits[0] };

            JobHandle _jobHandleRay = RaycastCommand.ScheduleBatch(raycastCommands, raycasthits, 1);
            _jobHandleRay.Complete();

            JobHandle jobHandle = job.Schedule();
            jobHandles.Add(jobHandle);
        }

        JobHandle.CompleteAll(jobHandles);

        jobHandles.Dispose();
        raycastCommands.Dispose();
        raycasthits.Dispose();
    }
}


[BurstCompile]
public struct RaycastTest : IJob
{
    public RaycastHit raycastHit;
    public void Execute()
    {
        if (raycastHit.collider != null)
        {
            Debug.Log("hit");
        }
    }
}
```

What am I missing here? I tried the suggested approach in the Raycast Command documentation but it obviously failed.

The main error I get is this :

> UnityException: FindObjectFromInstanceID can only be called from
> the main thread. Constructors and field initializers will be executed
> from the loading thread when loading a scene. Don't use this function
> in the constructor or field initializers, instead move initialization
> code to the Awake or Start function.
> UnityEngine.RaycastHit.get_collider () (at
> :0) RaycastTest.Execute () (at
> Assets/scripts/simpleRaycast.cs:60)
> Unity.Jobs.IJobExtensions+JobStruct`1[T].Execute (T& data,
> System.IntPtr additionalPtr, System.IntPtr bufferRangePatchData,
> Unity.Jobs.LowLevel.Unsafe.JobRanges& ranges, System.Int32 jobIndex)
> (at :0)

If anyone here have any raycasts in their Unity jobs please enlighten me, even part of your code will help a lot, I failed to find any examples online and the documentation on the subject is scarce.

#### SUMMARY:

I need Raycasts in a function I want to multithread using the Unity Job System. I tried the approach that was suggested in the documentation but it failed so I tried for some time to move stuff around without really knowing what I was doing.

Answer (score 0):

The error is coming from

> UnityEngine.RaycastHit.get_collider ()

As the error is telling you: You can't use `RaycastHit` and its properties within a job.

I think you misunderstood the concept of `RaycastCommand` a little => You want do perform the raycasts themselves async within Jobs -> but then you want to handle the results in the Unity main tread after the `CompleteAll`!

See e.g. the [Example](https://docs.unity3d.com/2022.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/RaycastCommand.html)

It depends a bit what you are after

If you just want to check if **ANY** of those 5000 raycasts hits something

=> You only need 1 single result

```
public class simpleRaycast : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private List<Agent> agentList;

    [Serializable]
    public class Agent
    {
        // TODO somehow provide ray origin and direction
    }

    void Start()
    {
        agentList = new List<Agent>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
        {
            agentList.Add(new Agent());
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        var raycastCommands = new NativeArray<RaycastCommand>(agentList.Count, Allocator.TempJob);
        // only need a single result
        var raycasthits = new NativeArray<RaycastHit>(1, Allocator.TempJob);

        for (int i = 0; i < agentList.Count; i++)
        {
            var agent = agentList[i];

            // TODO: where does every agent get origin and direction from?
            raycastCommands[i] = new RaycastCommand(agent.origin, agent.direction, QueryParameters.Default);
        }

        var handle =  RaycastCommand.ScheduleBatch(commands, raycasthits, 1, 1, default(JobHandle));

        handle.Complete();

        var hasHit = raycasthits[0].collider != null;
        if(hasHit)
        {
            Debug.Log("Has hit at least one object!");
        }

        raycastCommands.Dispose();
        raycasthits.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Or you want to get all hits then you probably need up to `5000` results. **However** afaik this way there is no way to tell exactly which agent has hit which object. The job can only tell you that the given set of raycasts has hit a set of colliders (up to the given amount).

```
public class simpleRaycast : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private List<Agent> agentList;

    [Serializable]
    public class Agent
    {
        // TODO somehow provide ray origin and direction
    }

    void Start()
    {
        agentList = new List<Agent>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
        {
            agentList.Add(new Agent());
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        var raycastCommands = new NativeArray<RaycastCommand>(agentList.Count, Allocator.TempJob);
        var raycasthits = new NativeArray<RaycastHit>(agentList.Count, Allocator.TempJob);

        for (int i = 0; i < agentList.Count; i++)
        {
            var agent = agentList[i];

            // TODO: where does every agent get origin and direction from?
            raycastCommands[i] = new RaycastCommand(agent.origin, agent.direction, QueryParameters.Default);
        }

        var handle =  RaycastCommand.ScheduleBatch(commands, raycasthits, 1, agentList.Count, default(JobHandle));

        handle.Complete();

        foreach (var hit in raycasthits)
        {
            if (hit.collider != null)
            {
                Debug.Log($"Has hit {hit.collider}", hit.collider);
            }
        }

        raycastCommands.Dispose();
        raycasthits.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips, unfortunately this is a simulation for my pathfinding that uses and depends on tons of raycasts. I'm trying to "jobify" the pathfinding since its heavy on the CPU. If I understand correctly, there is no way to make this work within a job? So I have to find a workaround for my pathfinding and replace all the raycast somehow? Thanks again! EDIT: to clarify, I do need every agent to have their own raycast and process independently of each other so I need all the results and within their respective job